# Does YouTube have a 30 video limit when scraping using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, youtube

I understand the key concepts to **scraping YouTube** is to carry out the following automated actions using **Selenium**, **Webdriver** and **Python**:

- Launch Chrome browser (or firefox)
- Authenticate YouTube "I Agree" button
- Supply a YouTube URL
- Determine the scroll height of the page
- Scrape video content

I have created the script below that successfully launches the Chrome browser, authenticates the "I Agree" button, launches the YouTube URL and scrolls down the page whilst carrying out the Title, Views and Posted Date scraping in the background.

## Issue

In my test whilst scraping a YouTube **VIDEOS Page with 108 videos**, it **only captures the first 30 videos**.

Behind the scenes, it cycles through the script identifying 4 different **scroll heights** 2264, 3812, 5576 & 6380 respectfully.

However each scroll height duplicates the original capture (first 30 videos).
Thus, I get 30 unique video captures (titles, views and posted dates) presented 4 times with a total video count being 120. If all was working well I should get 108 unique video captures.

I have read many articles on Stackoverflow, but cannot find any reference material to address this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

## Python Script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
import time 

# Row & Column Viewing Options
pd.set_option("max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", None)

# Removes SSL Issues With Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('log-level=3') 
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

# Get URL
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/c/JohnWatsonRooney/videos?view=0&sort=dd&flow=grid'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

# Auto Consent Youtube
consent_button_xpath = '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/form/div[1]/div/button/span'
consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, consent_button_xpath)))
consent = driver.find_element_by_xpath(consent_button_xpath)
consent.click()

# Get scroll height
current_scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
print('> Current Scroll Height (before loop):', current_scroll_height) #starts at 2264

# Locate individual YouTube Video 
videos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')
video_list = [] # Create array for video list (video_item > video > videos)


# Loop: YouTube page load to end of scroll
while True:
    # Scroll to bottom of page
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", current_scroll_height)
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(1)
    print(' - Current Scroll Height (while loop):', current_scroll_height)

    # Extract title, views & date posted from individual youtube video
    for video in videos:
        title = video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]').text
        views = video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]').text
        post_date = video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text

        # Store individual YouTube video information within dictionary
        vid_item = {
            'title': title,
            'views': views,
            'posted': post_date
        }

        # Store individual videos in main array video_list
        video_list.append(vid_item)

    # Use pandas to present main array containing individual videos + number of videos in array
    df = pd.DataFrame(video_list) 

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with current scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    print(' - New Scroll Height (after for loop):', new_height)
    if new_height == current_scroll_height:
        print(df)
        print('\nNumber of Videos (end of for loop):', len(video_list))
        break
    current_scroll_height = new_height

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. Not able to scroll.